# GLSL shader not writing to color_attatchment1

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glad

I am trying to render to multiple render targets, I set up a float texture and bound it to COLOR_ATTACHMENT1. This all works well and the buffer is created and bound properly. The buffer is even drawn to if I let all the shaders draw to it (`glDrawBuffers(..)`) instead of just the shader I have set up to draw to it (`layout (location = 1) out ..`). The issue is the shader that should be altering the values doesn't. I know this using Nsight graphics to preview `COLOR_ATTATCHMENT1`:

[image: COLOR_ATTATCHMENT1]

(note the white pixels on the left are a border from nsight)

As we can see, the buffer has two writes but neither change the buffer at all. The `glClear` shouldn't change anything here (I think) because `glDrawBuffers` doesn't contain this buffer yet.
This is what `COLOR_ATTATCHMENT1` looks like if I let every shader write to it (`glDrawBuffers(..) //with both attatchments`):

[image: GL_COLOR_ATTATCHMENT1]

These shaders don't write to this attatchment at all (`layout (location = 0)` no location 1) and work perfectly, but again, the one shader that does write to it doesn't. The crates should be writing white pixels, they can be seen here:

[image: postProcessed output]

(note: this screenshot has post processing applied)

I don't know it's not writing but every other shader has no problem. The framebuffer is set up properly:

[image: Framebuffer overview]

The texture is set up with a format of `GL_RGB32F` because I want this to be a float texture with the viewspace normals, but the problem persists if I use `GL_RGB` or `RGBA`. The framebuffer is multisampled and all the textures are multisampled. This is the creation code (ommited `glGen`.....):

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboMultisample);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, colourTexMs); //..
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, sampleLevel, GL_RGB, windowWidth, windowHeight, GL_FALSE); //..
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //..
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //.. magnified ..
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, depthTexMs);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, sampleLevel, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, windowWidth, windowHeight, GL_FALSE); //..
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //..
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //..
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, normalTexMs);
glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, sampleLevel, GL_RGB32F, windowWidth, windowHeight, GL_FALSE); //..
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //..
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //..
```

And this is the attachment code (`fboMultisampled` is still bound to `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`):

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); //unbind textures for safety
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0); //unbind textures for safety
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, colourTexMs, 0); //attatch textures to the framebuffer
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, depthTexMs, 0); //..
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, normalTexMs, 0); //.. 0 = mipmap level
```

And this is the shader that should be writing to `COLOR_ATTATCHMENT1` (`result` calculation is omitted):

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
layout (location = 1) out vec3 viewNorm;
//..

void main()
{
    //..
    fragColor = vec4(result, 1.0f);
    viewNorm = vec3(1.f);
}
```

So in short I don't understand why the shader isn't writing to `COLOR_ATTATCHMENT1`.

note: there aren't any OpenGL errors reported.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by outputting a vec4 in the shader even though the texture is rgb32F